# Display partial rows after the first row

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to take the following rows

username | id | role

```
SELECT u.username, u.id, r.role FROM ".TBL_USERS." u
 INNER JOIN ".TBL_ADMIN_ROLES." r ON r.userid = u.id
 WHERE u.userlevel > 3
```

At the moment, I use the following code to get the results.

```
<?php
            $q = $database->getAllAdmins();
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
            {
                ?>
                <a class="main" href="profile.php?id=<? echo $row['id']; ?>"><? echo $row['username']; ?></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><? echo $row['role']; ?></li>
                </ul>
                <?
            }
            ?>
```

Obviously, this is looping through and showing the username over and over.
What I want it to do is show the username once and then show every role below.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe try GROUP BY the u.id and then introducing some logic into the php that keeps track of the last name and if it changes it prints it out? just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q = $database->getAllAdmins();
$user = "";
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    if ($user != $row['username']) {
        if ($user != "") { echo "</ul>"; }
        echo "<a class='main' href='profile.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['username']}</a>";
        echo "<ul>";
    }
    echo "<li>{$row['role']}</li>";
    $user = $row['username'];
}
```

My answer is the same concept as the others, just cleaner.

Comment: Perfect, just takes finding a way around it!

Comment: Make sure to add a `ORDER BY u.id` to the query or else this wont work. Also, you need to echo the final `</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `ORDER BY i.id` to your query, you can then use a variable to keep track of the last user.

```
<?php
    $q = $database->getAllAdmins();
    $lastUserID = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
        $newUser = $lastUserID != $row['id'];
        if($newUser) {
?>
            <a class="main" href="profile.php?id=<? echo $row['id']; ?>"><? echo $row['username']; ?></a>
            <ul>
<?      }
?>
        <li><? echo $row['role']; ?></li>
<?      if($newUser) {
?>
        </ul>
<?      $lastUserID = $row['id'];
        }

    }
?>
```